How can I prevent NaN error when fitting data, and what is the best way to do so without skewing data?
#Load weather data
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\slick\Downloads\weather_dataset.csv")

#Hot encode data, for columns with information that is not 
df_weather_processed = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['Location','RainToday', 'WindGustDir', 'Cloud9am', 'Cloud3pm','WindDir9am', 'WindDir3pm'])

df_weather_processed.replace(['No', 'Yes'], [0,1], inplace=True
)

df_weather_processed.drop('Date',axis=1,inplace=True)
df_weather_processed = df_weather_processed.astype(float)
features = df_weather_processed.drop(columns='RainTomorrow', axis=1)
Y = df_weather_processed['RainTomorrow']

df_weather_processed.fillna(0)

#Split data into training and test sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( features,Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)

#Create instance of and train modelfor i in range(1,20,2):
    k = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i)
    k.fit(x_train, y_train.values.ravel())
    
    #Make predictions
    pred = k.predict(X_test)

    print("KNN ", i, ":")
    
    #Accuracy
    print("\tAccuracy: ", k.score(X_test, y_test))
    
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred).ravel()

    #Precision
    precision = tp/(tp+fp)
    print("\tPrecision: ", precision)

    #Recall
    recall = tp/(tp+fn)
    print("\tRecall: ", recall)
    
    #F1 score
    F1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
    print("\tF1 score: ", F1)
    
    #AUC
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, pred)
    roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
    print("\tAUC score: ", roc_auc, "\n")

Above, showcases my code that is being used to see whether it will rain tomorrow (Yes or No, binary classification). Most of my code flows fine, and at one point it even worked. But I have reached a snag and no matter how I have attempted to look at the problem and have looked up methods, I have seemed to reach a point where I need someone to point out what I can do unravel this tangle. Specifically, it is when using the X_test and y_test in fitting that I have run into the problem: a ValueError: Input X contains NaN. KNeighborsClassifier does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively.
Now, I considered several options on how to move forward. First, I looked for a different way to fit the data. But it still comes with the error.
neigh =  KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k).fit(x_train,y_train)  

I thought perhaps this was because of the dataset itself. Originally,
df_weather_processed.fillna(0)

was not part of my code. But after realizing most of the 'NA' values listed were a representation of zero, I added in hoping this would resolve my case. But it did not. Next, I thought perhaps I should add all columns but 'date' and 'RainTomorrow' into the pd.get_dummies line. This resolved ValueError: Input X contains NaN, but left instead Input Y contains NaN.
I also know this issue is not limited to KNeighborsClassifier either as I also tested it with both DecisionTrees and SVM models. It's something to do with fitting specifically which is a needed step in this process.
At this point, I knew I needed someone with a stronger skillset than me to explain to me what is the next step I should take while keeping myself on line for a K-NN classifer solution.  I would very much appreciate it if someone could explain why it's happening specifically (was I right about the NAs? Is it something else?) and how to prevent it in the future.

Well to begin with, fillna is not in place and unassigned, so it's a line in the air that you wrote. No wonder NaNs are still there. And yes, you have to ensure data quality. Training on NaNs, I should like that to raise an error. Also you mention an error about input X, yet your code shows no X being defined, unless I missed it.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
